# How to ask Mathematica to do the given operation for a set of parameters?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics, summation, sets, parameters

I have a set of numbers like this

`s = {a, b, c, d, e, f, ..., g, h}`

and I would like to ask Mathematica to do the following operation (to sum the subtractions of adjacent numbers)

`(a - b) + (c - d) + (e - f) + ... + (g - h)`

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: `s[[;; ;; 2]] - s[[2 ;; ;; 2]] // Total`?  Assumes the length is even

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you very very much :),  yes, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some more options

```
Clear[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h];
s = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h};
```

```
Total[Table[s[[n]] - s[[n + 1]], {n, 1, Length[s] - 1, 2}]]
```

```
Sum[s[[n]] - s[[n + 1]], {n, 1, Length[s] - 1, 2}]
```

```
Total[SequenceCases[s, {j_, k_} :> j - k]]
```

```
Total[Subtract @@@ Partition[s, 2]]
```

All give

> a - b + c - d + e - f + g - h

Answer (score 1):

A mathematical approach: $\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1} s_k$ translates as follows

```
s = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h};
Sum[(-1)^(k+1) s[[k]], {k, 1, Length[s]}]
(* a - b + c - d + e - f + g - h *)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
☺ = +## & @@ (#[[;; ;; 2]] - #[[2;; ;; 2]]) &;


☺ @ {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}
```

> ```
>  a - b + c - d + e - f + g - h
> ```